How do I perform Multiple Linear Regression using Statsmodels module when the data is in pandas
Im trying to do an MLR using data from two dataframes but one has a different size to the other hence Im getting endog and exog size mismatch. I was wondering if anyone could help me understand how to correct this and get a valid MLR.
Attached is the attempt made:
X = Reddit_WSB[['Sentiment_score (Body based)','Sentiment_score (Title based)']].values.reshape(-1,1)
X = X.iloc[:min_length]
y = final_df_twitter['Close'] 
y= y.iloc[;min_length]
X = sm.add_constant(X)
model = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()
print(model.summary())

Not a professional coder so would really appreciate the input! Thank you in advance!
final_df_twitter for context is the closing values of stocks from a long list in a df.
Was expecting a similar output to my SLR, I have read other posts but didn't find them helpful in fixing my issue and I most likely misunderstood but still would appreciate :)
UPDATE:
My SLR's look like this clarification however they also produce an R^2 of 0 so not sure if theyre correct either.
X = Reddit_WSB['Sentiment_score (Title based)'].values.reshape(-1, 1)
y = final_df_twitter['Close'] 
X = sm.add_constant(X)
model = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()
print(model.summary())

X = Reddit_WSB['Sentiment_score (Body based)'].values.reshape(-1, 1)
y = final_df_twitter['Close'] 
X = sm.add_constant(X)
model = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()
print(model.summary())

X = Reddit_WSB['Avg Sentiment Score'].values.reshape(-1, 1)
y = final_df_twitter['Close'] 
X = sm.add_constant(X)
model = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()
print(model.summary())


Regression assume that an observation row in y and x refer to the same case or instance, i.e. they need to be related. So, you need to merge the dataframes according to the index that pairs rows or observations of x and y. For example if the identifier is companies, then match on company name and drop observations that don't have the full record. e.g. join (or merge) in pandas.

So the final_twitter_df is inner joined on the Date, this was done earlier in my code as the stock info and the tweets were at first seperate.

The closing price of a day will not depend much on the sentiment. The sentiment should only have an effect on the change in stock prices.

Also, if change in stock price and sentiment are for one day observations, then causality will go both directions. Rumours or news spread through sentiment affect stock price, large drop or increase in stock price affects the sentiment. (OLS is not appropriate with endogenous explanatory variables)

Thats a good point, thank you for that comment! So it could be a more valid proposition to do a regression on the effects of the sentiment on say the volatility?

volatility might or will have the same endogeneity problem. For example, you could try instrumental variable regression using the sentiment of the previous day as instrument. However, I never looked at the sentiment literature, so this is just based on generic knowledge.

Please check this:
import statsmodels.api as sm

# Assuming Reddit_WSB and final_df_twitter are your pandas DataFrames

# Concatenate the two independent variables horizontally
X = Reddit_WSB[['Sentiment_score (Body based)', 'Sentiment_score (Title based)']]

# Ensure that the shapes of X and y match
min_length = min(len(X), len(final_df_twitter['Close']))

# Slice X and y to match the minimum length
X = X.iloc[:min_length]
y = final_df_twitter['Close'].iloc[:min_length]

# Add a constant column to the independent variables
X = sm.add_constant(X)

# Fit the multiple linear regression model
model = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()

# Print the summary of the model
print(model.summary())

Here you should have exactly the same number of records.
It can be a little bit problematic regarding removing some records.
You cal also verify empty records with null and reduce it at the beginning.

It returns a value error, ValueError: The indices for endog and exog are not aligned
